# Flask Babel convert to original language when insert to database

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I have a set of SelectField with **Flask-WTF** and I convert the default language with **Flask-Babel**.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
from flask_babel import _, lazy_gettext as _l

class PaymentStatus(enum.Enum):
    PENDING = _l('PENDING')
    COMPLETED = _l('COMPLETED')
    EXPIRED = _l('EXPIRED')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.value)

payment_status = [(str(_l(y)), y) for y in (PaymentStatus)]

class PaymentForm(FlaskForm):
    status_of_payment = SelectField(_l('Payment Status'), choices=payment_status)
    # ...
    # ...
```

And here is my model look like:

```
class Payment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'payment'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status_of_payment = db.Column(db.Enum(PaymentStatus, name='status_of_payment'))
    # ...
    # ...
```

And when I try to insert the value from the **Flask-WTF** form to my database, I got some error.

Here is the snippet how I insert it to database:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    payment = Payment(
        # payment_status=form.status_of_payment.data
        payment_status=PaymentStatus.PENDING.value
        # ...
        # ...
    )
```

The value of the `enum` `PENDING` also converted to the language on preferred language on my browser, so I got this error message:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.LookupError) "MENGUNGGU" is
>   not among the defined enum values

for more information: "MENGUNGGU" = is Indonesian language for "PENDING" in English.

So the problem here is, when I insert the `SelectField` value, it also converts the language to my preferred browser language, and my database which is **PostgreSQL** block it, because I don't define the value on my enum type.

So, the point of my question is, can we excluded the i18n & l10n value from **Flask-Babel** when we want to insert the value to a database..?, or what should I do to face this..?

Comment: My opinion is that you should not use the translate value on the enum. It doesn't make sense to me have a internacionalizated enum, handle internacionalization in the form tier

Comment: Another shorter option would seek for a mapping from intercionalizated value to deafault language on enum class it would have something to achieve this

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: No, your first answer also works in my case, I'll accept the answer later while now I still experimenting on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should swap values in your choices because the first element in the tuple is the actual value that will be submitted and the second one is the presentation:

`payment_status = [(y.name, _l(str(y.value))) for y in PaymentStatus]`

Thanks to this you'll have translated names and proper values submitted.

Enum's name should be stored in your database instead of the value.

Comment: I think the first answer before edited is more efficient, because we don't need to declare the `_l()` in each value of the enum variable. Just looping it like your first answer.

Comment: The correct answer is like this:
`payment_status = [(y.name, _l(str(y.value))) for y in (PaymentStatus)]`
swap the `_l()` position with `str()` position.